# Limit internet speed without tc

Tags: bandwidth, tc, puppy-linux

I have been using deb based Linux for years and I never had problems limiting the internet speed using wondershaper. On my sisters PC I had to install puppy Linux because it's a very old PC. The problem is, wondershaper won't work since it requires tc. I got a suggestion to try using trickle, which also seems to be a nice bandwidth shaper but I was unable to get it working on puppy.

Anyone has experience with puppy and bandwidth shaping, or maybe a suggestion how to get the tc command on puppy?

Comment: Puppy is based on Debian or Ubuntu, right? Can you use `apt-get`/`dpkg` to install the `iproute` package?

Comment: It's not based on debian nor ubuntu. It doesn't use the apt-get as package manager. Can't tell you now but I'm pretty sure it doesn't have dpkg neither. It's using it's own .pet packages...

Comment: Hmmm, Googling I see an iproute2 `.pet` package at http://www.smokey01.com/bruceb/ibiblio_quirky.html ... and it includes a `/usr/sbin/tc`. You sure you don't have a tc already? Debian has it in `/sbin/tc`, so maybe you're just looking in the wrong place?

Comment: Why bandwidth shaping on a very limited machine? Can't make any sense of it.

Comment: @derobert I will try the iproute2 tomorrow and see if works.

Comment: @vonbrand because my PC and her old PC are using the same router to get to the internet and sometimes if she is watching YouTube vids I'm experiencing lag.

Comment: the router is not openwrt capable by any chance? shaping works best on the router